# How do I add information to a row with already containing some cells?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using appendRow() to insert values in Google Sheet, and even if some fields are empty, it adds the values to the next line if any cell contains content.

Example: Cell C1 has a Sum formula, =SUM(A1,B1) When I insert a row with appendRow(), the values are added to A2 and B2 instead of A1 and B1, due to the content of C1.

Is there any way to solve this?

```
function showUserForm() {

  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("userForm");

  var html = template.evaluate();

  html.setTitle("Form");

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);

}

function appendData(data){

  var ws= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Records");
  ws.appendRow([data.depo,data.phone,data.game]);

}

function errorMsg(){

  Browser.msgBox("Name & Phone Required");

}
```

Comment: In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet, the whole script for replicating your issue and the output values you want? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: You are trying to [append a row](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendRow(Object)), but as you state, you already have an object in C1. Use `getRange()` instead.

Comment: If cell C1 already has content where do you want the value of data.game to go if date.depo and dara.phone get entered into A1 and B1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function appendData(data){
  var sh=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Records");
  var rg=sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow(),1);
  rg.setValue(data.depo);//column A
  rg.offset(0,1).setValue(data.phone);//column B
  rg.offset(0,3).setValue(data.game);//column D
}
```

or

```
function appendData(data){
  var sh=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Records");
  var rg=sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow(),1,1,4);
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  vA[0][0]=data.depo;
  vA[0][1]=data.phone;
  vA[0][3]=data.game;
  rg.setValues(vA);
}
```